# I want get specific image id from foreach loop in codeigniter through ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, foreach-loop-container

I want to get a specific record of an image from `foreach` loop then I want take this value to another page

```
<?php foreach($portfolio_image as $image):?>
    <h3><?=$image->portfolio_image_title?></h3>
    <p><?=$image->portfolio_image_detail?></p>
    <a id="lin" href="#portfolio-si" data-id="<?=$image->portfolio_image_id?>">
<?php endforeach;?>

<script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#lin').click(function(evt){
               evt.preventDefault()
                   $.ajax({
                       type : 'POST',
                       url  : "<?=base_url();?>index.php/home/single_portf",
                       data : {id:$('#lin').attr('data-id')},
                       cache : false,
                       success: function(data){
                           $('#portfolio-sig').html(data);
                       }
                    });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your post, things like what you have tried as well as what has / has not worked, as well as any other information you think may be helpful.

Comment: What problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class="lin"` like bellow :

```
<a id="lin" class="lin" href="#portfolio-si" data-id="<?=$image->portfolio_image_id?>">
```

Change jquery onclick function like bellow :

```
$('.lin').click(function(evt){
```

And then use jquery `$(this)` method like bellow :

```
data : {id:$(this).attr('data-id')},
```

So, Finally :

```
<?php foreach($portfolio_image as $image):?>
    <h3><?=$image->portfolio_image_title?></h3>
    <p><?=$image->portfolio_image_detail?></p>
    <a id="lin" class="lin" href="#portfolio-si" data-id="<?=$image->portfolio_image_id?>">
<?php endforeach;?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.lin').click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

        $.ajax({
           type : 'POST',
           url  : "<?=base_url();?>index.php/home/single_portf",
           data : {id: id},
           cache : false,
           success: function(data){
               $('#portfolio-sig').html(data);
           }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: i tired but i have four pictures and i always get id of first picture even i hover mouse on fourth picture

Comment: i already checked this it's returning me the first picture id

Comment: not possible that. `var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); console.log(id);` show this result

Comment: what is name of `class="lin"` parent class or id?

Comment: class of anchor tag

Comment: what is the name of `class="lin"` above class name ?